# Returning null values by the form elements in bootstrap modal laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

I have a blade template view in laravel 5 which contain form elements inside a bootstrap modal and outside a bootstrap modal within a same view. The problem is that I am only getting values from either form elements which are inside a bootstrap modal or which are outside a bootstrap modal through $request->input in controller.

> {!!
>   Form::open(['url'=>'test','class'=>'form-horizontal','id'=>'test_form'])
>   !!}

When I insert above form facade code inside bootstrap modal it works for inside elements and other elements outside modal part return null value. Same happen when I insert above code outside a bootstrap modal.I want to get value of all elements. I am unable to figure out what the problem is. So it will be grateful if anybody help me. 
Thanks in advance. Here is the sample html code

```
<div class="ibox-content">
    {!! Form::open(['url'=>'test','class'=>'form-horizontal','id'=>'test_form']) !!}
      <!-- for modal -->
      <div class="modal inmodal" id="testmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content animated fadeIn">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Test Modal </h4>
                        </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('insidemodal', 'Enter Balance', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']) !!}
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    {!! Form::text('inside_balance', null, ['id'=>'balance_remaining','class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                   {!! Form::button('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-white','id'=>'submit_button','data-dismiss'=>'modal'])!!}
            </div>
           </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('outsidemodal', 'Enter Balance', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']) !!}
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                    {!! Form::text('outside_balance', null, ['id'=>'balance_remaining','class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                    {!! Form::button('Trigger Modal', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-lg ','id'=>'modal_button'])!!}
                   </div>
      </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Jquery code looks like this:

```
//trigger modal 
$('#modal_button').click(function(){
    $('#testmodal').modal({
    show: true
  });

});

// to submit form
$('#submit_button').click(function(){
    $('#test_form').submit();
 });
```

Comment: Post a sample HTML of the view

Comment: I have edited my question with sample html of the view.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem is that you have a "submit" button inside the modal which dismisses the modal.

Here's the problem: if you show the modal, then fill in some values & click the modal submit button, then when the modal closes, the form is submitted. Without explicitly preventing the modal submit button from submitting in Javascript, I believe it will submit.

I think that if you were to enter values in the outside values, then invoke the modal and enter values, you would probably get all the values when you close the modal.

The solution will be to change the modal button from a submit button to just a plain old button. I *believe* that it will still close the modal, but you'll need to experiment with that.